# extracting JSON from from an http request response - Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm building a web scraper to extract product information from the product link.

the web url is the following: https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_header/

I found the HTTP request link for product details with chrome Dev Tools.

This is my code

```
class quoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Practice'
    
    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_header/']

    def parse(self,response):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/ajaxdetail_header/', callback = self.parse_detail, headers={'Accept': '*/*',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Cookie': '__cfduid=da54d7e9c59cf35860825eabc96d7f1c41612805624; _ga=GA1.2.1229230175.1612805628; _gid=GA1.2.205529574.1613135874',
'Host': 'scrapingclub.com',
'Referer': 'https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_header/',
'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="88", "Google Chrome";v="88", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})

    def parse_detail(self, response):

        product = ProductClass()

        data = response


        # im still debugging so im not putting it into an item yet

        # data = json.loads(response.text)
        # product['product_name'] = data['title']
        # product['detail'] = data['description']
        # product['price'] = data['price']

        yield {
            'value' : data
        }
```

When I run

```
scrapy crawl ProductSpider -O test.json
```

This is my output file

```
[
{"value": "<TextResponse 200 https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/ajaxdetail_header/>"}
]
```

Why isn't returning me the JSON content?

Comment: you are only returning the headers and not the body

`data = response.headers`

Comment: My bad, I was trying to extract the body. Anyways, putting response.body doesn't extract the JSON

Answer (score 0):

change header data to get the expected output

```
class quoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Practice'

    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_header/']

    def parse(self,response):
        headers = {
    'authority': 'scrapingclub.com',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_header/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': '__cfduid=d69d9664405f96c6477078a5c1fa78bb41613195439; _ga=GA1.2.523835360.1613195440; _gid=GA1.2.1763722170.1613195440',
}

        yield scrapy.Request('https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/ajaxdetail_header/',
                             callback = self.parse_detail, headers=headers)

    def parse_detail(self, response):

        product = {}

        data = response


        # im still debugging so im not putting it into an item yet

        data = json.loads(response.text)

        product['product_name'] = data['title']
        product['detail'] = data['description']
        product['price'] = data['price']
        yield product
```

Comment: This is still giving me a text response and not the JSON in the URL

Comment: convert json.loads(response.text). just copy my whole spider and run it.